# How to maintain Latex Math notation while creating PDF from a website using Adobe Acrobat DC 19

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, latex

I downloaded a website using Adobe Acrobat but the math notation are messy 
they are looking like this :

```
$a^{b+c} = a^b \cdot a^c$ and $a^{2b} = a^b \cdot a^b = (a^b)^2$.
```

anyway to fix this using Adobe or other software that can download the website maintaining actual math format ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Can you clarify whether your objective is to maintain the Latex notation (clean and transferable Latex code), vs. proper rendering on the displayed page as math?

Comment: As I said I downloaded cp-algorithms website through Acrobat for printing but the math notations didn't come as it should be. So my objective is to maintain the latex notation

Comment: Right, I read those same words in the question, which is what lead to my question.  Repeating the unclear words doesn't clarify them.  "Maintain Latex notation" could refer to either the Latex code, itself, or the rendered output of that code (appearance of the math expressions).  Which are you referring to?

Comment: i am referring to 2nd one . rendering the output of that code